# Download file from amazon aws using a pem

Tags: amazon-web-services, scp, pem

I am trying to download a file from amazon using

```
scp -r xxxxxxx@aws2.xxxxx.com:file.tar.gz  /Users/myname/Desktop
```

It asks for a pass but I use a PEM to connect

Is this possible or am I stuck with FTP?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are having an Aws Ec2 linux instance.

To connect using pem file.

```
scp -i yours.pem  xxxxxxx@awsec2ip:/path/to/file
```

Here

- yours.pem - your PEM key file
- `xxxxxxx` -  is the username you log in with
- `awsec2ip` -  is the IP or DNS alias of the instance
- `/path/to/file` -  is the location where the file is stored

This will copy the file into the current folder on the local machine.

Details on [Download/Save files from EC2](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=32922)

Another option could be through SFTP.
You can find the details of how to SFTP using your pem file [here](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/01/how-to-upload-and-download-files-in.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
scp -i /path/to/pem/file xxxxxxx@aws2.xxxxx.com:/path/to/file/file.tar.gz /Users/myname/Desktop
```

This command should work for tar.gz file. But if you want to copy a directory recursively you will have to use additional switch -r.